# javascript tabs not working correctly

Tags: javascript, tabs, babeljs

I have a question. Everything works fine, but if I add more tabs, so "isVisible" class is added to all other tabs. How do I fix this problem?

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <button class="nextTab">Next Tab</button>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs__item isActive">
      <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs__item">
      <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript (Babel)

```
(() => {
    const tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs')
        , tabsItem = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs__item')
        , nextTab = document.querySelector('.nextTab')

    nextTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for(let i = 0; i < tabsItem.length; i++) {
            tabsItem[i].classList.toggle('isActive')
        }
    })
})()
```

Comment: CSS: .tabs__item {
  display: none;
}
.tabs .isActive {
  display: block;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should track a current tab index in order to be able to switch to next one.

```
(() => {
    const tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs')
        , tabsItem = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs__item')
        , nextTab = document.querySelector('.nextTab')
        , currentTab = 0;

    nextTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (++currentTab > tabsItem.length - 1) currentTab = 0; 
      document.querySelector('.isActive').classList.remove('isActive'));
      tabsItem[currentTab].classList.add('isActive'))
    });
})()
```